# How does one converge to an SDE from a discrete approximation?

Tags: probability, analysis, numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations

It is well known that Euler approximation of an ODE
$$dx(t) = f(t,x(t))dt$$
can be defined as follows, for a uniform partition of coarseness $1/N$ over $[0,1]$,
$$ x_{t_{n+1}} = x_{t_n} + \frac{1}{N} f(t_n, x_{t_n}).$$

If we were to replace $1/N$ with $1/N^{1/2}$ does the Euler approximation scheme
$$x_{t_{n+1}} = x_{t_n} + \frac{1}{N^{1/2}} f(t_n, x_{t_n})$$
converges in $L^2$ to the SDE
$$dx(t) = f(t,x(t))dB_t$$
with $B_t$ being a brownian motion? Are there any reference to a similar result under *reasonable* assumptions?

Comment: You may wish to look up Donsker's theorem

Comment: Without a random source this scheme will never ever have something to do with an SDE . The standard method is to draw independent $\epsilon_n$ with mean zero and variance one and set $$x_{t_{n+1}} = x_{t_n} + \frac{1}{N^{1/2}} f(t_n, x_{t_n})\,\color{red}{\epsilon_n}\,.$$ Kloeden & Platen wrote an entire book about the subject.